# Monitor requires xrandr command to turn on every time it turns itself off to save power

Tags: linux, display, multiple-monitors, power-management, xrandr

Problem: A monitor fails to turn back on after going into power saving mode. I physically turn on the monitor, and it displays "No signal".

Note that when this happens, the computer itself is on, and has been on previously (in ACPI terms, the computer is in G0, S0, i.e. running).

However, the other monitor connected to the same system, gets a signal immediately.

Using the second monitor I'm puzzled to see that xrandr lists the monitor as connected and that it has the display mode I want already enabled. The monitor itself, simply doesn't display anything.

If I then re-issue the very same xrandr command used to initialize the system in the first place (from .xinitrc), then the culprit monitor turns on.

The following is the xrandr command I use to configure the displays (generated by arandr):

```
xrandr --output DP-0 --off --output DP-1 --off --output HDMI-0 --off --output DP-4 --mode 5120x1440 --pos 0x579 --rotate normal --output DP-3 --off --output HDMI-1 --off --output DP-2 --mode 1920x1200 --pos 5120x0 --rotate left --output DP-5 --off
```

This is the first time I've ever experienced this, and I've used systems since the CRT days, as well as setups that range from two, to four physical monitors.

Some monitors have some sort of built-in power saving feature, the monitor turns itself up, but wakes up when it receives a signal from the graphics card.

This is a new monitor and a supposedly somewhat high-end one, a "SAMSUNG Odyssey OLED G9 S49CG934". It works perfectly fine besides this, I doubt that it is damaged, considering that it works just fine besides this problem.

If it matters, this is Arch Linux with:

xrandr program version       1.5.2
Server reports RandR version 1.6

Hardware: This is an Nvidia 3090, I've used three monitors on it previously, with no issues like this.